# discord.js v13 slash command interaction failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The command doesn't run and I get an "interaction failed" error.

Please tell me which file is giving the error and how can I do it?

index.js:

```js
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('봇이 준비됐습니다!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return interaction.reply({content: '없는 명령어입니다...', ephemeral: true });

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return interaction.reply({ content: '명령을 실행하는 데 실패했습니다...', ephemeral: true });

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({ content: '명령을 실행하는 데 실패했습니다...', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

s();
keepAlive();
client.login(token);
```

commands/help.js:

```js
    async execute(interaction) {
    const helpembed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('red')
      .setTitle('명령어')
        return interaction.reply({embeds: [helpembed]});
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several things wrong with your code

File **help.js**:

- Have you imported the MessageEmbed constructor : `const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');`
- You can't do `.setColor('red')`, you have to do `.setColor('#ff0000')`

File **index.js**:

- `const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);` Why are you trying to fetch our interactions in commands ? Maybe you should try with `const command = client.interactions.get(interaction.commandName);` (if the collection of interactions was declared)

For more details about the error, maybe check on your console and provide the error if you have acces to it.